# Perform cell value modification without copy/paste - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, background-process

So I have a connection source where it imports an XML file from a URL. The XML contains a few dates that are formatted in mm/dd/yy, however Excel doesn't seem to be able to tell that it is 20xx and instead asks me to specify whether it is 19xx or 20xx after each refresh I do to the data (the data gets updated daily).

So I made a script that fixes that issue using copy/paste. Problem is that it is slow and it can't be done in the background. If I run the script while I'm on a different worksheet it would start changing sheets really quickly and freeze for a few seconds. Here is my code below:

```
Sub test()

Dim listCols As ListColumns
Set listCols = Sheets("RawData").ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns

'Sets the very last row & column to 0, to be copied later
Range("XFD1048576").Value = "0"

For col = 1 To listCols.Count 'Iterate through columns in table
    If listCols(col) = "DATECOL1" Or listCols(col) = "DATECOL2" Or listCols(col) = "DATECOL3" _
    Or listCols(col) = "DATECOL4" Or listCols(col) = "DATECOL5" Or listCols(col) = "RESERVATIONEND" Then

        For Each cell In listCols(col).DataBodyRange.Cells
            If cell.Value <> "" Then 'ignore empty cells
                'Copies the very last column & row
                With Range("XFD1048576")
                    .Copy
                End With
                'Pastes the '0' value from above and adds it to the original value in the cell it is pasting in
                With cell
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

Range("XFD1048576").ClearContents 'Clear the '0' in there

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

[image: Error in regards to the top answer]

EDIT2:
I'm not sure what it is, but using the .value = .value definitey works. I tested it using a simple code as shown below:

```
Sub test3()
With Range("W1:W59")
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her's a more efficient version of your code.  It avoids the copy/paste operation, and the loop throught the cells

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim listCols As ListColumns
    Dim col As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    Set listCols = Sheets("RawData").ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns

    FormatDates listCols("DATECOL1")
    FormatDates listCols("DATECOL2")
    FormatDates listCols("DATECOL3")
    FormatDates listCols("DATECOL4")
    FormatDates listCols("DATECOL5")
    FormatDates listCols("RESERVATIONEND")
End Sub

Private Sub FormatDates(ListCol As ListColumn)
    Dim rng As Range, arr As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ListCol.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each arr In rng.Areas
            With arr
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW. So much faster and cleaner, but still a slight problem. The same one that showed up with Siddharth Rout's answer. It gets to the last cell and then tries to go on afterwards, which results in the following error:
`Run-time error '1004':

No cells were found.`

Comment: + 1 Nice one Chris :) @Mo2: See the Explanation in my post. You need to apply the same thing (On Error Resume Next) in Chris's post as well

Comment: Thank you both, it works but with another slight problem. About 10 cells end up coming as #N/A.

Comment: @mo2 what where the original values of the cells that come up #n/a ?

Comment: EDIT: It seems that I have spoken too soon. His answer doesn't work. The values that come back are completely off. The dates are wrong. Image is attached in the OP.

Comment: So it works fine on the columns that are completely filled, but not on the ones that have some empty cells. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mo2 Just updtaed answer.  The issue is that when there are empty calls scattered in to table, `SpecialCells` returns a multi area reange.  Sorry, I overlooked that in initial answer, fixed now.  Also added Error Handler for case where the table is entirely empty, as Sid suggested

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Just to recap so that I understand exactly what's going on here:
1. The error handling you're talking about is when you check if `rng` is empty or not, correct?
2. When you say it returns an area range, what exactly does that mean? Is it like an array?

Comment: @Mo2 Yes, the error handler refers to `Set rng = ...SpecialCells(...)`.  If no cells match the `SpecialCells` criteria, then `SpecialCells` errors.  The `On Error ...` pair handle that.  `Rng` starts out `= Nothing`, and if there was a (handled) error, still equals nothing.  A _Multi Area Range_ is a range that refers to in a discontinuous set of cells, eg `Range("W1:W59,W65:W70")`

Comment: I found a bug with the code. The .NumberFormat should be set before the .Value = .Value

Comment: @Mo2 I've re-trested this code with the `.Value = ...` first, and it works fine for me (using Excel 2010)

Comment: Maybe in your situation. My code calls a data refresh to append new data to the table, which it adds at the very bottom of the table. There is no number format set in those cells yet so doing a simple .value=.value before setting a format won't change anything. You probably ran it on cells that already had data in them before so the format stayed the same from before. It only happens to the newly added cells after a RefreshAll is called (which happens before this piece of macro is executed).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't run anything written in VBA "in the background". VBA doesn't support multi-threading. You might possibly be able to get away with it with multiple instances of Excel though, but I'm not positive.

As far as speeding that up. Try adding:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

to the beginning and end of your procedure, respectively, and see if that helps you out.

*edit*

**IF** you wanted to be able to do this kind of thing in the background, you would need to look at writing an add-in for Excel with C# or VB.NET, as they support multi-threading and can run in the background while the user does something else. (If executed properly)

Comment: Well that partially helped. It doesn't change worksheets anymore, but I still can't do anything until it finishes doing everything. I'm gonna add it to my code, though. Thank you

Comment: Correct, unfortunately working on a worksheet in the same instance of Excel that a VBA sub is running is is not possible. You would need to look into developing a multi-threaded add-in to get this type of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through every cell in the range and then doing a pastespecial, identify the non blank cells in one go. For that you can use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

For example

```
ws.columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).PasteSpecial _
xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
```

or (**UNTESTED**)

```
listCols(col).DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).PasteSpecial _
xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
```

**FollowUp from comments.**

My apologies. I forgot to mention one thing. You will get an error if it doesn't find non blank cells and hence you need to use On Error resume next

For example

```
Dim Rng As Range '<~~ Declare this at the top
```

And use this inside the loop

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = listCols(col).DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
                     xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd

    Set Rng = Nothing
End If
```

You can reduce your code further by using SELECT CASE

```
For col = 1 To listCols.Count 'Iterate through columns in table
    Range("XFD1048576").Copy

    Select Case listCols(col)
    Case "DATECOL1", "DATECOL2", "DATECOL3", _
    "DATECOL4", "DATECOL5", "RESERVATIONEND"
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Rng = listCols(col).DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
            Rng.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        End If
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Where do I put that piece of code and what do I remove from mine?

Comment: Updated my post. You can use the 2nd piece of code in lieu of FOR/NEXT

Comment: Yours is close and seems to be better, but there is one slight problem. It doesn't stop after it reaches the last one and comes back with an error saying "no cell was found" and here is the code changes:

Comment: `For col = 1 To listCols.Count 'Iterate through columns in table
    If listCols(col) = "TIMESTAMP" Or listCols(col) = "STATETIME4" Or listCols(col) = "STATETIME" _
    Or listCols(col) = "RELEASEDATE" Or listCols(col) = "RESERVATIONSTART" Or listCols(col) = "RESERVATIONEND" Then
        
        For Each cell In listCols(col).DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            Range("XFD1048576").Copy
            
            cell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
            cell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
  
            Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: Updated my post. You may have to refresh it.